How to retrieve and fetch data from a document's field on firebasefirestore?
I am trying to fetch data from a document on a Firebase's collection that contains users:

As you can see, there is a collection named Users and two users, and now I click on one you get to see the fields and their values.
What I need is to retrieve the data within the documents (the field values) and use it for my app, this is something that is easily accomplished in Java by using a class variable member. However, with Kotlin I can't do that, so I can't get the data I want out of the scope of the method addOnColeteListener (I use it like this db.collection().document().get().addOnCompleteListener{ // do stuff to retrieve data }, see code bellow).
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val notificationsDatabase: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    val numberOfNotifications: Int = setNotifications(notificationsDatabase)
                    var currentUser: UserInfo
                    val mapOfUser: MutableMap<String, String?> = emptyMap<String,String?>().toMutableMap()
                    var dataSets = listOf<String>()
                    setUserInfo { user ->
                        currentUser = UserInfo().copy(
                            firstname = user.firstname,
                            lastname = user.lastname,
                            email = user.email,
                            phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber,
                            gender = user.gender,
                            moreInfo = user.moreInfo,
                            uri = user.uri
                        )
                        logMessage("outsideCurrentUserIs", currentUser.toString())
                    }
//                    logMessage("outsideCurrentUserIs", currentUser.toString())
                    MainBody(
                        UserInfo(
                            firstname="Emmanuel",
                            lastname="Agyapong",
                            email="xyz@google.com",
                            phoneNumber="1234567890",
                            gender="Male",
                            moreInfo="An incoming software engineer who's madly in love with Android :)",
                            uri="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bookme-dc582.appspot.com/o/meAtBCC.jpg?alt=media&token=3d9b481c-9880-445f-939f-3b7bb60f3cbd"
                        ),
                        numberOfNotifications
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private fun setUserInfo (callBack: (UserInfo) -> Unit) {
    val firebaseFirestoreInstance = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val database: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    database.collection("Users")
        .document(firebaseFirestoreInstance.uid.toString())
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.successful) {
                val u: UserInfo = UserInfo().copy(
                    firstname = task.result.data!!["firstname"].toString(),
                    lastname = task.result.data!!["lastname"].toString(),
                    email = task.result.data!!["email"].toString(),
                    phoneNumber = task.result.data!!["phone"].toString(),
                    gender = task.result.data!!["gender"].toString(),
                    moreInfo = task.result.data!!["moreInfo"].toString(),
                    uri = task.result.data!!["profileImage"].toString()
                )
                callBack(u)
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Cached get failed: ", task.exception)
            }
        }

}

I tried to retrieve data from a document on Firebase, but I noticed that I could store the info in a variable only within the scope of .addOnCompleteListener{}. Still, after that, the variable is empty as if I just initialized it. However, when I print the results inside of the adOnCompleteListener{}, I can see the values. How did I try to solve the problem? I implemented different data structures and implemented callback, but nothing worked.
EDIT 1:
I Added two pictures so that @Frank van Puffelen can see them. I defined a local variable (currentUser = UserInfo()) and assigned it the values of the user in the database through addOnCompleteListener{ currentUser = UserInfo().copy(...)} and printed it twice. The results are there, inside the cope of the listener, I can see the values being retrieved, but outside of it, they are empty as if the variable was defined with no values.
printing of carrentUser inside of addOnCompleteListener{}
currentUser printing outside of addOnCompleteListener{}
Samething happens with addSuccessfulListener{}.
EDIT 2:
Hi all, I am on Ecstasy for finding a solution to the addOnCompleteListener, which is an asynchronous method, and why whichever code executes outside of it finished earlier instead of the code within itself. Hence, I could not extrapolate the information within the database (firebase). To fix this problem, I have added a piece of code -- called a listener from another database. It is not a real solution, but it fixed mine, and I tried everything, even delaying the execution using launch{delay()} or Timer, but with no positive outcome.
setNotifications()
readData(object : MyCallback {
    override fun onCallback(myMap: MutableMap<String, String>) {
        Log.d("m0", myMap.toString())
        mapOfUser.putAll(myMap)
        Log.d("m1", mapOfUser.toString())
    }
})

Just one more thing, I noticed that the print statements keep going and basically never stop, but for everything else, it works.

The code looks fine at first glance, but your screenshot has a field named profileImage while the code calls it userProfileImageURI. If that is supposed to be what the code reads, the names need to line up exactly. We also can't see any field username in the screenshot, but given the above I recommend checking for typos there too.

@Frank van Puffelen what you're seeing is the data field from another project (the one in Java)... so yeah they are different. I am erasing the Java code since it is from another project, but I was trying to make a point -- that I could fetch and store data and use it outside of the cope of the .onAcompleteListener in Java using a class variable member—something I can't do in Kotlin.

Thanks for cleaning up the code. Please read how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example to prevent this type of distraction going forward. --- For now, did you debug the program locally already? I.e. if you set a breakpoint on if (task.isSuccessful) {, does it reach that? If you then step through the code line by line and check the value of each variable on each line, is there anything that is different from what you'd expect?

Thanks for the link shared above, I appreciate it. Yes, it reaches the point where I go to task.isSuccessful and beyond. Meaning, that when I store the values on a variable I can print them within the addOnCompleteListener{}, but not outside... which is where I need to use them -- on the composable function.

I Added two pictures so that you can see them. I defined a local variable (currentUser = UserInfo()) and assigned it the values of the user in the database through addOnCompleteListener{ currentUser = UserInfo().copy(...)} and printed it twice. The results are there, inside the cope of the listener, I can see the values being retrieved, but outside of it, they are empty as if the variable was defined with no values.

That's a classic async problem, which should have nothing to do with the difference between Kotlin and Java. The code in a callback runs much later than the code after/outside that callback, which you can most easily verify by adding some debug print statements and checking the order in which they run. I added some links that explain this in more detail.

Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it!

@FrankvanPuffelen thanks I found a solution although not perfect it was 11:57 pm yesterday—temporary solution on the edit.

You can use a success listener in Kotlin just like in Java.
firebasefirestore.collection("Users")
        .document("currentUserId")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            if (document.exists()) {
                userProfileImageURI = document["userProfileImageURI"] as? String
                username = document["username"] as? String
            } else {
                // handle user not exists
            }

        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            // handle firebase error
        }

Or if you prefer to parse to a data class, since you have a user info class, you just need to make sure your data class has default values for all fields
data class UserInfo(firstname:String = "", lastName:String = "")

Then you can parse to an object
firebasefirestore.collection("Users")
    .document("currentUserId")
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
        if (document.exists()) {
            val userInfo = document.toObject(UserInfo::class.java)
        } else {
            // handle user not exists
        }

    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        // handle firebase error
    }


Thanks for sharing your answer. I am aware that I can get access to the listener just like I do in Java. However, I seem not to be able to get the value outside of the listener. Like, I would store the values in a class variable in Java and that would do (it can be used in any method across the class), but there is no class variable that I can use in Kotling because I am using composable functions. So I can't use val userInfo = document.toObject(UserInfo::class.java) outside of addOnSuccessListener{...} I used a callback method, but with no success.

Change your user info declaration to
var currentUser: UserInfo = remember { UserInfo() }
So that in your callback the currentUser is updated properly for Composable State.

It's the same weird thing. As soon as I find the solution, I'll post it here.

thanks I found a solution although not perfect it was 11:57 pm yesterday—temporary solution on the edit.
